# Create subsets from a dataframe by a combination of factors

Tags: r, list, dataframe, loops, apply

I need to do pairwise, iterative analyses by column on a large dataset. The first column contains categorical variables and the rest numerical. For example, for dataframe df:

```
df <- data.frame(T = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"), G = c(1.1, 2.3, 7.4, 8.4, 8.1, 8.2), H = c(2.4, 1.3, 3.1, 4.5, 9.6, 7.2), I = c(2.5, 1.1, 7.2, 9.7, 10.8, 8.5))
```

I need to do t-test on V2, V3, V4 for all a/b/c combinations. I created two lists:

```
ls1 = combn(c("a", "b", "c"), 2)
ls2 = colnames(df[2:ncol(df)])
```

and use them to create sub-datasets by

```
pair <- function(x) {data.x <- df %>% filter(T %in% x)}
df_sets <- apply(ls1, MARGIN = 2, pair)
```

I can then take each of the sub-dataset to to t-test for each column and retrieve the p-values by

```
data1 <- as.data.frame(df_sets[[1]])
ttest_p_by_col <- function(y) {(t.test(get(y)~T, data = data1, var.equal = T))[["p.value"]]}
p_t_tab <- unlist(lapply(ls2, ttest_p_by_col))
```

and repeat the last process with data2, data3. However, in the real case, I have a dataset much longer than a/b/c, making manually repeating this process laborious. I tried to automate the as.data.frame(df_sets[[i]]) part using loops

```
for(i in 1:ncol(ls1)) {data[i] <- as.data.frame(df_sets[[ [i] ]])}
```

but apparently I can't have [i] in [[ ]]. How can I get the sub-datasets from the df_sets list as individual dataframes? Or is there a better way to create the subsets by apply() to avoid retrieving them out from a list? I've also tried to create the sub-datasets using loops directly

```
for(i in 1:ncol(ls1)) {data[i] <- df %>% filter(T %in% ls1[,i])}
```

but run into the problem of using [] in filter(). I'm new to R and hope that there's a straightforward way to get this task done. Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It looks like you might be overthinking this - here's what google had to say: https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/how-to-perform-t-test-for-multiple-groups-in-r/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`combn` accepts a function so you can perform `t.test` for every combination in the function itself. With `sapply` you can do this on every column in `ls2`.

```
sapply(ls2, function(y) combn(c("a", "b", "c"), 2, function(x) {
  data.x <- subset(df, T %in% x)
  t.test(reformulate('T', y), data = data.x, var.equal = TRUE)[["p.value"]]
}))

 #         G      H      I
#[1,] 0.0155 0.1599 0.0434
#[2,] 0.0086 0.0383 0.0282
#[3,] 0.6681 0.0804 0.5531
```